# Creating custom formatting for a pivot table based on another table with identical dimensions (R)

Tags: r, pivot-table, dt

I have two pivot tables as below. I need the main table to get its formatting from the bottom table based on the rule specified. I am not entirely sure of how to pass formatting from the one table to the other given we are only passing the one table object. I'd be able with any solution either within this package or in DT.

(Commented in code at the right position but essentially the cells on the first table should be coloured in based on the observations on the bottom table(if less than 5, the cell needs to be flagged red))

```
library(radiant.data)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

#this data needs to show on the pivot table
df_data_to_show <- pivotr(diamonds, cvars = c("clarity","cut","color"), nvar = "price", fun = "sum") %>% dtab()

df_data_to_show$x$data
#>          cut color    I1    SI2    SI1    VS2    VS1   VVS2   VVS1    IF  Total
#> 1       Fair     D    NA  34428  27750   5688     NA     NA    875    NA  68741
#> 2       Fair     E  1232  26484  13094   2551     NA    738     NA    NA  44099
#> 3       Fair     F 10852   3633  24775  14812  16797     NA  12648  3205  86722
#> 4       Fair     G  1954  25521  16846  11654   3419   3323     NA    NA  62717
#> 5       Fair     H 10152  38344  38153   7516  26427     NA     NA    NA 120592
#> 6       Fair     I  6268  13440   2804   3867   3065     NA     NA    NA  29444
#> 7       Fair     J  2304  23181    497     NA  16732     NA     NA    NA  42714
#> 8       Good     D  4346  59491  21960   6361   4522  19324   4274    NA 120278
#> 9       Good     E  2608  77762  75916  62827  14774   2511   2129    NA 238527
#> 10      Good     F  3354  59098  40587  47473  21560     NA  15886  1429 189387
#> 11      Good     G  7026  43708  47079  34603  34942  10284  26112   895 204649
#> 12      Good     H    NA  38845  47938  35801   8032  15198    638    NA 146452
#> 13      Good     I    NA  11686  82335  11858  38485   5221   9301   945 159831
#> 14      Good     J    NA  36827  33588   5202   1128     NA     NA    NA  76745
#> 15 Very Good     D    NA  83312  57617  42237  36710  14682   1426 18114 254098
#> 16 Very Good     E  6707 164585 112414  90421  45633  46216  16852 16474 499302
#> 17 Very Good     F 10640  90164 173023 104353  57590  24961  15475 22877 499083
#> 18 Very Good     G  2988 133754  91859  63196  90789  97253  24230  2151 506220
#> 19 Very Good     H  2850  73086 124936  71239 103507  15029   6475  2571 399693
#> 20 Very Good     I    NA  47089 102178 101361  47980   1289  11335  7951 319183
#> 21 Very Good     J    NA  74032  69433  44767   2849  10161   2042    NA 203284
#> 22   Premium     D 13119  60845 146063  36107  75983  12910   5952    NA 350979
#> 23   Premium     E  3572  96571 132717 135139  70399  32273   7701  6144 484516
#> 24   Premium     F  5896 144000 100753 135135  59548  15123   7718 18160 486333
#> 25   Premium     G 19580 148256 111278 180735 100370  39591  18677  1847 620334
#> 26   Premium     H 13321 203818 160108 161620  98884  17926  10046  3028 668751
#> 27   Premium     I  6436 126824 112927  91604  50340  23292   4553  3729 419705
#> 28   Premium     J  2195  93865  42461  96399  79836  12850    994  9596 338196
#> 29     Ideal     D    NA  36893 111255 128776  78128  60124  15407  4216 434799
#> 30     Ideal     E    NA 117900 126845 118332  58749  81276  42797  7323 553222
#> 31     Ideal     F 23323 114836 137310 153054 108434 132094  90199 44013 803263
#> 32     Ideal     G    NA 108961 102594 206233 176063 186596 167161 28904 976512
#> 33     Ideal     H  7068 136811 201787 128418  40020  23152  27539 29354 594149
#> 34     Ideal     I    NA 115069 113838  81508  72743  40227  26039  5263 454687
#> 35     Ideal     J    NA  34881  78256 106134  30380   4317   9814   569 264351

#the cells above should be coloured in based on the observations here (if less than 5, the cell needs to be flagged red)
df_data_to_color <- pivotr(diamonds, cvars = c("clarity","cut","color"), nvar = "price", fun = "n_obs") %>% dtab()

df_data_to_color$x$data
#>          cut color I1 SI2 SI1 VS2 VS1 VVS2 VVS1 IF Total
#> 1       Fair     D NA   8   4   2  NA   NA    1 NA    15
#> 2       Fair     E  1   5   5   2  NA    1   NA NA    14
#> 3       Fair     F  2   1   4   4   4   NA    1  1    17
#> 4       Fair     G  1   5   5   2   2    1   NA NA    16
#> 5       Fair     H  3   4   9   2   3   NA   NA NA    21
#> 6       Fair     I  4   2   1   2   2   NA   NA NA    11
#> 7       Fair     J  1   3   1  NA   2   NA   NA NA     7
#> 8       Good     D  1  14   9   3   3    4    1 NA    35
#> 9       Good     E  1  16  22  15   5    1    2 NA    62
#> 10      Good     F  1  11  14  12   8   NA    7  2    55
#> 11      Good     G  1   7  10   8   7    3    3  1    40
#> 12      Good     H NA   7  13  10   3    3    1 NA    37
#> 13      Good     I NA   2  14   2   5    1    1  1    26
#> 14      Good     J NA   5  11   2   2   NA   NA NA    20
#> 15 Very Good     D NA  18  21  17  10    8    2  1    77
#> 16 Very Good     E  2  30  37  26   9   25    7  4   140
#> 17 Very Good     F  2  24  40  23  25   14    4  4   136
#> 18 Very Good     G  1  29  23  17  22   21   16  2   131
#> 19 Very Good     H  1  14  21  20  19   12    6  2    95
#> 20 Very Good     I NA   7  18  16  11    1    4  2    59
#> 21 Very Good     J NA  10  11  12   3    2    1 NA    39
#> 22   Premium     D  3  13  38  12  13    9    4 NA    92
#> 23   Premium     E  1  25  47  41  13    7    7  3   144
#> 24   Premium     F  2  23  25  36  17    6    4  6   119
#> 25   Premium     G  2  35  26  42  30   10    9  2   156
#> 26   Premium     H  3  31  31  25  23    5   11  3   132
#> 27   Premium     I  1  21  20  17  14    4    3  3    83
#> 28   Premium     J  1   9   9  12  10    2    1  1    45
#> 29     Ideal     D NA  15  39  55  24   20    9  1   163
#> 30     Ideal     E NA  30  36  55  25   22   21  5   194
#> 31     Ideal     F  4  34  42  53  29   29   29 18   238
#> 32     Ideal     G NA  21  31  50  51   43   42 16   254
#> 33     Ideal     H  1  30  43  31  22   13   14 15   169
#> 34     Ideal     I NA  14  23  19  18   14   12  5   105
#> 35     Ideal     J NA   6  18  16   8    3    1  1    53

#somehow combining the two tables
```

Comment: It is from radiant.data

Comment: What formating do you want to give to the table?

Comment: #the cells above should be coloured in based on the observations here (if less than 5, the cell needs to be flagged red)